# TypeScript define generic type for array whose member types match object property types

Tags: arrays, typescript, object, typescript-generics

I have a code like below (which is not correct).
My goal is to define a type for an array that can match member property types from an object.
In this case I would like to have:

`Cells<Row>[0]` to be type number and `Cells<Row>[1]` to be type string.

```
interface Row {
  first: number;
  second: string;
}

type Cells<T> = [{
  value: typeof keyof T;
}]

const r: Row = {
  first: 1,
  second: "Hi"
}

console.log(r);

function getCells<T>(r: Row): Cells<T> {
  return Object.values(r).map((v) => ({
    value: v
  }));
}

console.log(getCells<Row>(r));
```

I have looked into "Array-like" objects but unsure how these work in TypeScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now doing it more explicitly which works great:

```js
type ColTypes = [number, string];
type Cell<T> = { value: T };
type Cells<T extends any[]> = { [K in keyof T]: Cell<T[K]> }
```